# Program to print a word with most number of vowels

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am unable to figure out what is wrong with this code. Whatever I provide as input, the code prints i as output. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class VowelClass{

public static void main(String args[]){

String input;
System.out.println("Please enter your sentence: ");

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
input = scan.nextLine();

int maxVCount = 0;
String mostVowels = null;
String[] words = input.split("");

for (String word : words) {

  int vCount = 0;
  word = word.toLowerCase();

  for (int i=0; i<word.length(); i++){
    char x = word.charAt(i);
    if (x == 'a' || x == 'e' || x == 'i' || x == 'o' || x == 'u'){
    vCount++;
    }
  }
   if (vCount > maxVCount) {
    maxVCount = vCount;
    mostVowels = word;
   }
  }
    System.out.println("Word with most vowels is:");
    System.out.println(mostVowels);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you change your `input.split("")` to `input.split(" ");`

Comment: Thanks! that was embarassing

Comment: In the future, try debugging or SOP-gating your output, i.e. `System.out.println(word);` for sanity-checking purposes. Fastest way to find a typo.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the advise @Compass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input.split("");` => `input.split(" ");`

You need to split between the words, so use the 'space' character in the split method.

Comment: Which word has the most vowels:   flyby, the, cwmy, yellow or strengths ?

Comment: Indeed. Yellow is the winner :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class sen_wo
{

    String sen;

    void inputString(String sen1)
    {
        sen=sen1;
        int l=0,noc=0,wctr=0;
        char ch=' ';
        String wo="";
        l=sen.length();
        String word[]=new String[l];
        for(noc=0;noc<l;noc++)
        {
            ch=sen.charAt(noc);
            if(ch!=' ')
                wo+=ch;
            else
            {
                word[wctr++]=wo;
                wo="";
            }
        }
        word[wctr]=wo;
        int wctr1=0,cctr=0;
        String wor="";

        for(wctr1=0;wctr1<=wctr;wctr1++)
        {
            String bw=word[wctr1];
            int ctr=0;
            for(noc=0;noc<bw.length();noc++)
            {
                char ch1=bw.charAt(noc);
                if(ch=='A' ||ch=='U' ||ch=='I' ||ch=='E' ||ch=='O')
                    ctr++;
            }

            if(ctr>cctr)
            {
                cctr=ctr;
                wor=word[wctr1];
            }
        }
        System.out.print(wor+"is having maximum no of consonant");
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.